# Why Buttons are resizing on click

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, java-8

I'm doing a simple Calculator, and the problem is with Buttons. When I click them they're slightly shrinking on the bottom which i don't want to do. Also, when I click on textArea the white dots disappears, but when I click on Buttons, dots around textArea show again. Why? How to make them permamently unvisible?

I tried to put in css in .button:pressed code that will set size of button to normal size but it doesn't work. They're shrinking anyway.

Main.java

```
package gui;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){Calculator.main(args);}
}
```

Calculator.java

```
package gui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Calculator extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    private TextArea screen;
    private Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonPlus, buttonMinus,
    buttonDevide, buttonTimes, buttonEqual, buttonDot, buttonSign, buttonClear, buttonPercent, buttonClose, buttonMinimalize;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        buttonClose = new Button(" ");
        buttonClose.setId("buttonClose");
        buttonMinimalize = new Button();
        buttonMinimalize.setId("buttonMinimalize");
        buttonClose.setLayoutX(0);
        buttonClose.setLayoutY(0);
        pane.getChildren().add(buttonClose);
        buttonMinimalize.setLayoutX(15);
        buttonMinimalize.setLayoutY(-1);
        pane.getChildren().add(buttonMinimalize);
        buttonClose.setOnAction(e->System.exit(0));
        buttonMinimalize.setOnAction(e->primaryStage.setIconified(true));


        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        //primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Calculator.class.getResourceAsStream("Icon.png"))); - Don't worry, I hid this for you
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        gridPane.add(pane,0,0);
        //Buttons
        int row = 1;
        screen = new TextArea();
        screen.setId("screen");
        screen.setEditable(false);
        gridPane.add(screen,0,row,4,1);

        row++;
        buttonClear = new Button("AC");
        buttonClear.setId("buttonClear");
        gridPane.add(buttonClear,0,row);

        buttonSign = new Button("+/-");
        buttonSign.setId("buttonSign");
        gridPane.add(buttonSign,1,row);

        buttonPercent = new Button("%");
        buttonPercent.setId("buttonPercent");
        gridPane.add(buttonPercent,2,row);

        buttonDevide = new Button("/");
        buttonDevide.setId("buttonDevide");
        gridPane.add(buttonDevide,3,row);

        row++;
        button7 = new Button("7");
        gridPane.add(button7,0,row);

        button8 = new Button("8");
        gridPane.add(button8,1,row);

        button9 = new Button("9");
        gridPane.add(button9,2,row);

        buttonTimes = new Button("x");
        buttonTimes.setId("buttonTimes");
        gridPane.add(buttonTimes,3,row);

        row++;
        button4 = new Button("4");
        gridPane.add(button4,0,row);

        button5 = new Button("5");
        gridPane.add(button5,1,row);

        button6 = new Button("6");
        gridPane.add(button6,2,row);

        buttonMinus = new Button("-");
        buttonMinus.setId("buttonMinus");
        gridPane.add(buttonMinus,3,row);

        row++;
        button1 = new Button("1");
        gridPane.add(button1,0,row);

        button2 = new Button("2");
        gridPane.add(button2,1,row);

        button3 = new Button("3");
        gridPane.add(button3,2,row);

        buttonPlus = new Button("+");
        buttonPlus.setId("buttonPlus");
        gridPane.add(buttonPlus,3,row);

        row++;
        button0 = new Button("0");
        button0.setId("button0");
        gridPane.add(button0,0,row,2,1);

        buttonDot = new Button(".");
        gridPane.add(buttonDot,2,row);

        buttonEqual = new Button("=");
        buttonEqual.setId("buttonEqual");
        gridPane.add(buttonEqual,3,row);

        stackPane.getChildren().add(gridPane);

        //---------------------- DRAG AND DROP
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
        stackPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
                dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
                dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
            }
        });
        stackPane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);

                primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            }
        });
        //------------------------ END OF DRAG AND DROP

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane,250,480);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Calculator.class.getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(480);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(250);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
class Delta { double x, y; }
```

Style.css

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: #000;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
}
#screen{
    -fx-pref-height: 150px;
    -fx-pref-width: 230px;
    -fx-control-inner-background: #000000;
    -fx-focus-color: #000000;
    -fx-text-box-border: #000000;
    -fx-background-color: #000000;

    -fx-focus-color: black;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: black;
    -fx-text-box-border: black;
}
.button{
    -fx-pref-height: 50px;
    -fx-pref-width: 50px;
    -fx-background-radius: 100;
    -fx-font-size: 15;
    -fx-font-Weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: #333333;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
}
.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
.button:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
#button0{
    -fx-pref-height: 50px;
    -fx-pref-width: 110px;
}
#buttonPercent, #buttonClear, #buttonSign{
    -fx-background-color: #A5A5A5;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
}
#buttonPercent:hover, #buttonClear:hover, #buttonSign:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #b0b0b0;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
}
#buttonPercent:pressed, #buttonClear:pressed, #buttonSign:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: #969696;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
}
#buttonDevide, #buttonTimes, #buttonMinus, #buttonPlus, #buttonEqual{
    -fx-background-color: #FD9500;
}
#buttonDevide:hover, #buttonTimes:hover, #buttonMinus:hover, #buttonPlus:hover, #buttonEqual:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #ffa421;
}
#buttonDevide:pressed, #buttonTimes:pressed, #buttonMinus:pressed, #buttonPlus:pressed, #buttonEqual:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: #f08e00;
}
#buttonClose{
    -fx-background-color: #e00000;
    -fx-background-radius: 100;
    -fx-pref-height: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 10px;
    -fx-font-size: 1px;
}
#buttonMinimalize{
    -fx-background-color: #1045c2;
    -fx-background-radius: 100;
    -fx-pref-height: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 10px;
    -fx-font-size: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this buttons effect add this to .button in Style.css

```
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
```

[To read here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/11009604/10474557)

To remove black dots in textArea corners you can wrap screen into Pane :

```
    Pane blackPane = new Pane();
    blackPane.setId("blackPane");
    screen = new TextArea();
    screen.setId("screen");
    screen.setEditable(false);
    blackPane.getChildren().add(screen);
    gridPane.add(blackPane, 0, row, 4, 1);
```

and add CSS property:

```
    #blackPane #screen {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    }
```

[Again to read here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169273/10474557)

It worked fine in my case.

And a few tips for the future:

- Don't mix the view layer with control layer, it's making terrible mess in your code. Add .fxml files where you can create view. You can easy build view in clear way using [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).
- Read and execute advice of your IDE(recommended Intellij). You have a lot repeats and complicated, bad formatting pices of code. For example:

  ```
  stackPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
          dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
          dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
      }
  });
  ```

can be replaced by this:

```
stackPane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
            dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
        });
```

Comment: For the dots, you could simply have a light gray border around the textarea. Just change to `-fx-background-color: lightgray;` in the #screen in the css.

Comment: With this advice with MouseEvent - I copied this from Stack. After I wrote about my problem i edited my code and i provided lamda e-> so, yeah... But thank you. About mixing, At this point i only know how to code in Swing without Mixing things. I started JavaFX tutorial like few days ago, maybe two, and I decided to wait with videos and try to built something just by myself and with small stack help. Just to check what I can do and to learn some stuff that I can use later while learning on Udemy. At this point i don't know much about FXML. First I want to learn JavaFX and then the rest

Comment: I know about Scene Builder, but... I think i have to first understand how to write good  code and than i can use some helpful tools like Builder. Thank you for you answer <3

Comment: Ok, all is working now! Thank you! 
#screen .content {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
}
Did the thing with dots! Buttons work too!